# Are these eggs on this Sugarcane Jujube leaf?

Tags: fruit-trees, leaves, insects

This is a leaf from a [Sugarcane Jujube](http://ediblelandscaping.com/products/trees/Jujubes/sugarcane.php) tree in Arizona. Are these eggs on the underside of this leaf? If so, what type of insect would they be from?

[image]

Comment: It could be a cocoon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a moth or butterfly, some Skipper eggs look like these. I suggest you look on butterfliesofamerica.com. 
May I suggest that you take a real macro shot, as in 1:1 and then just crop the portion with the eggs. Might be easier to make a more refined guess.